# Error during app installation

Tags: windows-10, installation

[image: The error message]

I'm trying to install XSplit Broadcaster on my Win 10 and every time it's interrupted by this "Could not set file security for file..." message. Does anyone know how to fix this? Haven't managed to find any useful tips so far.

Comment: Kindly check if methods in this article was helpful: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/error-1926-could-not-set-file-security-file-configmsi-error-5

Comment: @Sunny Thank you so much! The first tip behind the link did the trick :)